# Is there a way to figure out if an NDArray is trainable?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, mxnet

Is there a way to figure out if an `NDArray` variable has a gradient/requires backprop, similar to the `requires_grad` attribute in [pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch)?

I've tried checking whether `x.grad` is `None`, but that doesn't work for intermediate variables:

```py
import mxnet as mx

x = mx.nd.array([1, 2])
x.attach_grad()
with mx.autograd.record():
  y = x**2
  z = 2 * y
z.backward()

>>> print(x.grad)
[4. 8.]
<NDArray 2 @cpu(0)>
>>> print(y.grad)
None
```

In this example, `x` has a gradient but the intermediate variable `y` does not, but it should also be trainable.

I've tried looking through the source code, but can't figure it out.